# vim on Windows: syntax highlighting colorschemes only partially working

Tags: windows-10, vim, colors

When I use vim in my terminal (with  "set background=dark" set), certain keywords are highlighted as black. As my terminal background is black, I cannot see these specific keywords.

I am using the "wombat.vim" colorscheme I downloaded at "https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes"

On investigating the colorscheme file, I can see that the color scheme present in my terminal doesn't precisely match what the file states. for example, the file has line

```
hi Comment    guifg=#99968b    gui=italic
```

Which states that comments should be italic. My comments are not italic.

As I change from and to the wombat colorscheme, there are things changing in my terminal so I know that vim is loading the colorscheme, just not correctly.

EDIT: the colorschemes work correctly with gvim

Answer (score 0):

The `gui..=...` definitions are only valid for the GUI version of Vim, GVIM. The wombat colorscheme doesn't contain any `cterm...` definitions for color terminals. There's a wombat256.vim colorscheme, but that only only targets terminals that offer 256 colors. The Windows command prompt only supports 16 colors, though, so it's of no use. In the terminal, you need to choose a different colorscheme that provides basic terminal color definitions; i.e. `ctermfg=` in the range of `0..15`, or basic color names like `Cyan` or `Red`.